# What is the most modern way, the most "right" way to iterate through a vector, in c++11

Tags: c++, vector

I'm learning C++ now and I'm seeing so many ways to iterate through a vector.
I was wondering, since I want to learn it the right way, what's the most correct approach to iterate, nowadays?

Comment: It depends on what your needs are. If you need to save an index, or a set of indexes, then iterate using indexes. If you need to save an iterator for later, then iterate using iterators. If you just need to do something with every item in the container, then use e.g. [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) or some other [algorithm function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). There is no "one solution fits all", use what fits your situation and your needs best (which will of course be different at different place in the same program).

Comment: I changed it, i was hyperbolizing things. But you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the following factors:

1. Do you need the iterators inside your loop or just the elements?
2. Do you prefer Almost Always Auto (AAA) or Almost Never Auto (ANA)?

For example, if you just want to loop over some copies of the elements of a `std::vector<int> v`, you can do:

```
for (int element : v) {
   // Use element
}
```

If you're an AAA person, you would write `auto element` instead.

If you want to avoid a copy, you want a const reference:

```
for (int const &element : v) {
  // Use element
}
```

If you're an AAA person, you would write `auto const &element` instead.

If you want to modify the values inside the vector, then you want an modifiable reference:

```
for (int &element : v) {
  // Use element
}
```

Once again, if you like AAA, then `auto &element` instead.

If you need the iterators inside the loop:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); ++it) {
  // Use it
}
```

And if you're an AAA person:

```
for (auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); ++it) {
  // Use it
}
```

Note that a ANA person would also use `auto` if the code within the loop didn't depend on the actual type (which is not very common).

Also note that you can often avoid loops entirely by using the appropriate algorithms from `<algorithm>`. Check out [Sean Parent's talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning) for some information on this. He suggests that any loop with more than a few lines in it is bad and can usually be written much neater.

Comment: AAA is an anti-pattern, but ANA can be as well, if you take it too far.  In particular, `auto` was designed largely to avoid the verbosity of specifying the type of an iterator, when usually, you don't care about its type (and you know that whatever `begin()` returns, it will support `++`, comparison with `end()` and `*`).  A reasonable person will not be AAA nor ANA, but rather "use auto when appropriate, when it doesn't obfuscate, and don't use it when it obfuscates."

Comment: @JamesKanze I think it doesn't matter too much, since both are just alternatives until we have concepts in variable declarations. I just prefer something that is consistent, rather than something based on "Well... this should probably be clear." But yes, a middle-ground is just as valid.

Comment: I haven't seen Sean Parent's talk (I have no audio on this machine), but loops have to be in functions, and any function over about 10 lines is bad (in general---as usual, there are exceptions: it's hard to get a switch with 100 cases in 10 lines, for example).

Answer (score 2):

There is no correct approach for all contexts. The simplest one is the `for` loop:

```
std::vector<SomeClass> v;
for (SomeClass& sc : v)
   sc.Method();
```

But in some cases `std::for_each` may be better, or even the good old `for(;;)`.

Comment: You sould make that `auto const&` for the general case.

Comment: @Quentin Actually, for `vector<int>`, you don't want the reference.  In general, `for ( int i : v )` would be preferable; don't make the reader have to search for the type.

Comment: @JamesKanze that falls under "do's and don't's of `auto`". I personally never use `auto` if the type is short enough / one single word (yay, autocompletion !).

Comment: @Quentin In general, `auto` is obfuscation.  Except, of course, when it's not---writing out a 40 character type when it's initialized with a call to `begin()` or `end()`, and the only operations on it are `++`, `==` and `*` (and the only interesting thing is the results of the `*` operation) is obfuscating, and that's what `auto` was designed to solve.  But I'd be very skeptical of its use elsewhere.

Comment: @JamesKanze that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/)...They are specially designed for this purpose and work for all STL data-structures

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/

^ Link will help understand with example

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you iterate through a vector depends on the purpose of your iteration. Examples follow.

**Standard library algorithms**

If a standard library algorithm exists for your purpose, use it. This covers searching, accumulating, transforming, etc. when the operation can be represented simply using a lambda, function or functor. It also allows you to iterate over a range of your choice, by providing appropriate iterators, i.e. not just `begin` and `end`.

Example: Compute the sum of the first 20 elements of a vector

```
std::vector<int> v = { /* fill as appropriate */ };
int sum_20 = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::begin(v)+20, 0);
```

Example: Double each element and store in another vector

```
std::vector<int> v = { /* fill as appropriate */ };
std::vector<int> doubled;
doubled.reserve(v.size()); // avoid reallocations
std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 
               std::back_inserter(doubled), [](int x){return x*2;})
```

**Range-based for**

Example:

```
std::vector<int> v = { /* fill as appropriate */ };
for (int& x : v)
{
    do_something_with(x);
    do_another_thing_with(x);
    if (some_condition(x))
    {
        do_something_else();
    }
}
```

This works well for iterating over the *whole* container, where the operation you would like to perform is more complex than you'd like to represent in a trivial lambda, but not large enough (or used more than once) to justify a function of its own.

You can also customise, to an extent, the way you access the elements. If the elements are large, and you're only reading them, you can specify `const foo&`:

```
for (const MyBigObject& : MyBigContainer) { /* ... */ }
```

If you need to modify them, drop the const:

```
for (MyBigObject& : MyBigContainer) { /* ... */ }
```

And for small objects, or where you require a copy, drop the reference:

```
for (int x : MyVecInt) { /* ... */ }
```

This allows you to specify the most appropriate constness for your access, and control whether you're accessing by reference or value. Similar things can be done with standard library algorithms by providing const or non-const iterators, in conjunction with an appropriate argument type for any function/functor/lambda provided to algorithms that take a callable entity.

Note that range-based for will only iterate over the entire container, and there is no trivial way to iterate over two or more containers at the same time. This limits its applicability compared to...

**Regular for**

If you need to iterate over several containers simultaneously, or you need access to the index or iterator, as well as the element itself, a regular for loop can be the right approach. This is the most flexible, allowing you to customise just about every aspect of your iteration, but it won't take advantage of any standard libary optimisations, and typically requires rather more boilerplate to set up the pair of iterators / indices, check whether you're within the bounds of the container, etc.

Examples:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v2 = {2, 4, 6};
for (std::vector<int>::size_type idx = 0; idx < v1.size(); ++idx)
{
    std::cout << v1[idx] * v2[idx] << ", ";
}

std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
auto iter = v1.cbegin();
const auto end = v1.cend() - 1;
for (; iter != end; ++iter)
{

    std::cout << *iter + *(iter+1) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why you're iterating.  In many cases, *you* shouldn't iterate at all; use one of the standard algorithms.  Otherwise, if you want to visit all of the elements, of only one container, the ranged `for` is the best solution.  If you might want to break the iteration early, then prefer a normal `for`, unless (often the case) you need the iterator after the loop, in which case a `while` might be better; in both cases, using iterators.  Finally, if you're iterating over several vectors in parallel, it's probably clearer to use one index rather than several iterators.

In sum, there's a reason why you have so many choices.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise the range-for loop (since C++11)

```
vector<int> myVector {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
for (const auto& i : myVector)
  cout << i << endl;
```

Pre-C++11:

```
std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myCallable);
```

C++14 will not add anything regarding this scenario; probably C++17 will, with parallel loops.

In case you need to work with indexes, you may go for a "raw" for

```
for (auto i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i)
```

These are the most common ways. If you need something more specialized, like sorting, moving, finding, look at `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Your last snippet is a good example of an abuse of `auto`.  What's wrong with writing `int`, and telling the reader that you do know the type.  (And of course, in some cases, you might prefer `ptrdiff_t` to `int`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Because it is *not* `int` but rather `vector<int>::size_type`.

Comment: Which is exactly why I said to write it out in full.  If you'd have written `for ( size_t i = 0 ...`, it would be `size_t`.  As you've written the code, it's `int`, which in some cases, will _not_ be what you want.  (Whether you choose `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` here is debatable.  If the _only_ use of `i` is to index into the array, one can argue both ways.  If you do any numerical calculations based on `i`, however, you want to avoid the unsigned types.)

Comment: @JamesKanze In that case `auto` such as `int`, `size_t`, `vector<int>::size_type` are all correct because there are only 5 elements in the `vector`. Yes, in case of big `vector`s or when you cannot deduce its size, you should use `size_t` or the equivalent `decltype(myVector.size())`.

Comment: Or `ptrdiff_t`, if you're doing anything other than just indexing with the index; `size_t` is unsigned, and unsigned in C++ are somewhat broken, and should be avoided.  (One could easily argue that the container interface is broken, since `v.size() == v.end() - v.begin()` should be an invariant, which would imply that both have the same type.  Which they don't.)

Comment: Rather than `decltype(myVector.size())`, why not `std::vector<T>::size_type`?  (In practice, I'd only use something like this in template code.)  If I were using `decltype`, then it would be `decltype(myVector.end() - myVector.begin())`, in order to get a usable type.

Comment: As you said, you'd use `std::vector<T>::size_type` if you were working with templates. Consider, though, that although `decltype(myVector.size())` is rather verbose, it's inefficient:
`for (decltype(myVector.size()) i = 0; i < *myVector.size()*; ...)`
you're calling it twice. If you can, this one is good too:
`for (auto i = myVector.size(); ...)`.

Comment: `for (decltype(myVector.size()) i = 0; i < myVector.size();...)`, you're calling `myVector.size()` n + 1 times (where n is the size of the vector).  `for (auto i = myVector.size(); ... )`, you'll have to iterate in reverse, and it can be tricky.  (Remember, in that case, `i` is an unsigned type, so `>= 0` is always true.)  But I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  `decltype(myVector.size())` doesn't call the function.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. About a reverse loop, I said that if you can (no need to process in a particular order) you might use it. Furthermore, it'll be faster (you call .size() only once). I think we are going too off, though.

Comment: You can write a forward loop calling size only once as well.  And writing a backwards loop using an unsigned type as index can be a bit tricky.